# How to use java regex to match a line

Tags: java, regex

The raw data is:

```
auser1 home1b
auser2 home2b
auser3 home3b
```

I want to match a line, but it doesn't work using `^(.*?)$`

However, I can use `a(.*?)b` to match `user1 home1`.

How can I match `auser1 home1b`

Comment: Show the line of code you are using: the `^(.*?)$` expression should work.

Comment: Why can't you split on new-lines?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

By default, `^` and `$` match the start- and end-of-input respectively. You'll need to enable MULTI-LINE mode with `(?m)`, which causes `^` and `$` to match the start- and end-of-line:

```
(?m)^.*$
```

The demo:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String text = "auser1 home1b\n" +
                "auser2 home2b\n" +
                "auser3 home3b";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^.*$").matcher(text);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("line = " + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
line = auser1 home1b
line = auser2 home2b
line = auser3 home3b
```

### EDIT I

The fact that `^.*$` didn't match anything is because the `.` by default doesn't match `\r` and `\n`. If you enable DOT-ALL with `(?s)`, causing the `.` to match those as well, you'll see the entire input string being matched:

```
(?s)^.*$
```

### EDIT II

In this case, you mind as well drop the `^` and `$` and simply look for the pattern `.*`. Since `.` will not match `\n`, you'll end up with the same matches when looking for `(?m)^.*$`, as @Kobi rightfully mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Can you tell me why ^(.*?)$ match nothing?

Comment: Another sneaky option is matching for `.*`.

Comment: @performanceuser Also note that MULTI-LINE mode `(?m)`, which affects the `^` and `$` anchors, is independent from SINGLE-LINE mode `(?s)`, which affects the `.` operator. You can sensibly combine MULTI-LINE and SINGLE-LINE mode, but that is not what you want here.

Comment: @performanceuser By default, MULTI-LINE mode is disabled, so `^` and `$` only match the start and end of the input string, not after and before each newline within the input string. And SINGLE-LINE mode is disabled, so `.` does not match newline characters. That's why `^.*$` does not match an input string with newline characters.

Comment: @performanceuser, see **EDIT I** why `^(.*?)$` didn't match anything in your case.

Comment: Technically, `^` and `$` match the start/end of a **line**, and `\A`, `\a`, `\Z`, and `\z` are for start/end of **input**. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Comment: @EntangledLoops I find the docs are not too clear about that. They are only start- and end-of-line chars when multi-line-mode is enabled (which by default, it isn't). So just saying they're start- and end-of-line chars is IMHO misleading.

Comment: @BartKiers Yeah, I was being a bit pedantic and you're correct, the docs aren't very clear at all. The examples even use unexplained matching patterns and you're supposed to somehow appreciate the output. They should really fix that.

Answer (score 3):

we can also use the flag `MULTILINE`,

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^.*$",Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(text);
```

This will enable the multiline mode which will gave you the expected result.